# Use ng-messages-include with angular 1.5 components/es6 modules

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ecmascript-6, components, ng-messages

I would like to use the ng-messages-include directive to clean up my app's input validation by specifying a template for my default error messages. My problem is that since I am using the new component structure and making everything as modules, I can't figure out how to tell angular how to locate my template file unless I simply hardcode the template into my app's index.html like:

```
<script type="text/ng-template id="err-messages">
  <div ng-message="required">Required Message</div>
  ...
</script>
```

How would I link to my template file using `<ng-messages-include src="[???]"></ng-messages-include>` with the angular component/es6 module structure?

Comment: The things don't really change with components or ES6. Please, show the approach that works for you with Angular < 1.5 and directives.